# c++ deduce bool class template argument by constructor choice

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-argument-deduction, ctad

I am trying to deduce a bool template argument by the choice of the class constructor.
A simple example:

```
template <typename A, bool Condition>
class Subrange {
    public:
    Subrange(A a) requires (not Condition); /* create Subrange<A, false> */
    Subrange(A a, int b) requires (Condition); /* create Subrange<A, true> */
};
```

Is this even possible or do one have to explicitly specify Condition on the constructor?
PS: Condition does not rely on A.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, `Subrange<A,false>` has a `Subrange(A a, int b)` constructor and viceversa

Comment: @al3c you are right I've edited the code

Answer (score 7):

You can define [user-defined deduction guide](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction#User-defined_deduction_guides) for class template argument deduction (CTAD) (since C++17) as:

```
template<typename A> Subrange(A a) -> Subrange<A, false>;
template<typename A> Subrange(A a, int b) -> Subrange<A, true>;
```

Then

```
Subrange s1(0);    // -> Subrange<int, false>
Subrange s2(0, 0); // -> Subrange<int, true>
```